# How to add some space/indentation in enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate, thesis

I'm writing a thesis using UTM.sty, as provided below:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The package UTMthesis.sty will produce the output    %
% of a thesis according to UTM Thesis Manual,          %     
% School of Graduate Studies, 2007.                    %
% Yusof Yaacob, Department of Mathematical Sciences,   %
% Faculty of Science,  Universiti Teknologi Malaysia   %
% 81310 Johor Bahru, Malaysia                          %
% e-mail: yusofby@utm.my                               %
% 24 December 2009                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX cod for chapter header
\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@}   %  \vspace*{15\p@}
  {\parindent \z@ 
      \centering  
    \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
      \normalsize 
           \bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter 
       \par\nobreak
              \vskip 1.4\baselineskip 
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize     
         \bfseries #1\par\nobreak 
       \vskip 1.4\baselineskip %
  }}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{
  %\vspace*{20\p@} % \vspace*{20\p@} %
  {\parindent \z@  
    \centering  
    \normalfont 
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize 
    \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
         \vskip 1.4\baselineskip  
  }}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
%------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for layout
   %\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.2cm}
   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.7cm}   %\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.46cm} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
   \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm} %  \setlength{\textheight}{24.5cm}
   %\setlength{\headheight}{2mm}
    %\setlength{\headsep}{10.175mm}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for 1.5 spacing
   %\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{doublespace}
\setstretch{1.5}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  indentation
   \setlength\parindent{.5in}
   \usepackage{indentfirst} %1st line indented after section...
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for space between paragraph
  \makeatletter
    %\setlength{\parskip}{1.5\baselineskip \@plus 3ex
                %  \@minus 2.0ex}
    \setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip \@plus .01ex
                  \@minus .01ex}
   \makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for no hyphenation and right justified
    \hyphenpenalty=10000 \sloppy
    \raggedbottom
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command to get rid of default running head
   \pagestyle{myheadings}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for  page number 
%  \makeatletter
%    \renewcommand{\ps@plain}{%
%    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hfill\textrm{\thepage}}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}
%    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}
%    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}  }
%   \makeatother
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

 %For section font
 % \usepackage{sectsty} 
  %  \chapterfont{\centering\normalsize\uppercase}
  %  \sectionfont{\normalsize\uppercase}
   % \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
   % \subsubsectionfont{\itshape\normalsize}
%---------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for REFERENCES name
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change vertical space in section and subsection
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
  {section}%      % the name
  {1}             % the level
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm}    %{0.5cm}    % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection
  {subsection}%   % the name
  {2}             % the leve2
  {0cm}           % the indent
  {1.0cm}         % the beforeskip
  {0.01cm} %{0.5cm}        % the afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries} } % the style
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands to change horizontal space in section and subsection
% for times romans
   \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
   \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}} 
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Commands for  TocLoFT
  \usepackage{tocloft}
    %\cftsetrmarg{2.75cm} %    
     \cftsetrmarg{1.5cm} %  
       \cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm} 
       %\cftsetpnumwidth{1.25cm}
    \renewcommand{\cftdot}{} % get rid of dots
%Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}        % off tocname
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{.8cm}      % chapter indent
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{2.3cm}      % section indent
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{3.25cm}  % subsection indent
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{1.45cm}  % chp number width
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{1.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
   \renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\rule{0.75ex}{0ex}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
%-------------------------------------------------------------  
%List of Table
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  %\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{2.5cm}  
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{} % off lotname
%\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.015cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\cfttabindent}{-.1cm}      % table indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             \renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
\cftsetrmarg{3cm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
 %List of Figure
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{2.5cm}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{} % off lofname
\setlength{\cftfigindent}{-.1cm}      % figure indent %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\rule{2ex}{0ex}}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------------------------------------
% Command for bold caption
\makeatletter
  \long\def\@makecaption#1#2{\vskip 10\p@   % caption parameter
       \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1\,\,\,\,\,} #2} %%%%%
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize         % caption parameter
           {#1\,\,\,\,\,}  #2\par  % caption parameter
       \else                                   % caption parameter
           \hbox to\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}  % caption parameter
   \fi}                                            % caption parameter
\makeatother   
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{paralist} %refine list item
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,amssymb} % math symbols
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{graphicx} % .eps graphic
%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{lscape} % for landscape
%-------------------------------------------------------------- 
\usepackage{times}
%--------------------------------------------------------------
% Theorem-Like-Environment
\usepackage{theorem}
{\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[chapter]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}{\rule{0ex}{5ex}Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[chapter] }
%--------------------------------------------------------
\newenvironment{proof}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Proof}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{paragraph}
          {Solution}\vspace{-1cm}}{\end{paragraph}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to add some space/indentation in the enumerate environment. My current working code is as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\let\my@xfloat\@xfloat
\makeatother

\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{book}
%\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{UTMThesis,enumerate,amsfonts,longtable,qtree,etoolbox,array,rotating,pgf,tikz,tikz-cd,algorithm,csquotes,hyperref,lscape}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@xfloat#1[#2]{
    \my@xfloat#1[#2]%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \@normalsize \normalsize
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\qquad}
\makeatother

\allowdisplaybreaks
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix, positioning, shapes, shapes.geometric, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}
\let\openbox\relax
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax

\newcommand*{\qed}{\hfill\ensuremath{\square}}

%-------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{cite}                       % change  cite from [1,2,3] to [1-3] etc for number system
\makeatletter                           % change from
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}     % [1] to 1. etc 
\makeatother                            % in list of references
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\voffset}{-2.1cm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-.4cm}  
%--------------------------------------------------------
\font\fiverm=cmr5 
%\input{Pictex.tex} % using pictex
%---------------------------------------------------------
%\pagestyle{plain}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}  
\cfoot{\vspace{-.35cm}\thepage}  % 
\rfoot{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{Introduction}          %Chapter 1
    
    \section{Objectives of the research}
    
    Here are the objectives of the research:
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item To develop a new technique of ordering square matrices of EEG signals during a seizure.
        
        \item To show that the elementary components of electroencephalography (EEG) signals can be written as a sum of semisimple and nilpotent parts via Jordan-Chevalley decomposition.
        
        \item To build a theoretical foundation of the elementary components of the EEG signals, i.e., to find the relationship between the theory of prime numbers and elementary EEG signals.
        
        \item To present three real-time examples of Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of elementary EEG signals.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

that produce the following:

[image]

I want to produce the numbered list to look like this one:

[image]

How do I ahcieve this?

Comment: You can do that with  `enumitem`. I'd try something like `\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=1cm]` or whatever value you please.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments